# Display records in a subform on a tab

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a form with tab controls on it. On each of the tabs I have a sub form. One of my sub forms uses a table as a record source. If I open the sub form by itself it works perfect. It allows me to move through several records and view them one at a time. If I insert the sub form in the tab, it no longer displays any records. I have data entry set to no.

Comment: Has the Child Master properties in the sub form container control been "magically"  filled out for you? If they have then delete them.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the issue by switching to VBA code to INSERT INTO. It works perfect.